# How to integrate xkeyval keys with Lua code

Tags: lua, xkeyval, directlua

I am currently maintaining a template that uses `directlua` to compute a value based on a number of parameters defined as command keys with `keyval`. As it stands, it compiles correctly. However, when I try to adapt it, I obtain cryptic errors that I'm finding very hard to troubleshoot.

The template is a very complex one, what makes it difficult to create a coherent MWE, but here's my attempt:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{luacode}

\define@cmdkey{X}{y}[Z]{}
\begin{document}
  \setkeys*{X}{y="p"} 
  \directlua{
  if \cmdKV@X@y == "P" then
    var=1
  end
  }
\end{document}
```

I have tried some variants with the package `luacode` and importing the script from a different file using `dofile` and `require`, getting invariably an error that points somewhere at the end of the file. I suspect the Lua code doesn't like the `@`character, but I have not found any mention about that (or how to get around it).

So my question is: how can I evaluate command key-values using a Lua script?

---

**UPDATE 10.05.18:** As mentioned before, the original template is complex enough to make it difficult for me to extract a perfectly accurate MWE. This one, however, should be a bit better than the original one:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{luacode}

\makeatletter
\define@cmdkey{X}{y}[Z]{}

\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{
   \setkeys*{X}{#1}

   \directlua{
     if \cmdKV@X@y == "P" then
       var=1
     else
       var=2
     end
     token.set_macro("amacro", var)
  }
  \amacro
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \mycommand{y=P} 

\end{document}
```

If I replace `\cmdKV@X@y` with a more normal command (i.e., something like `\mymacro`), it works and evaluates correctly. However, as it stands, it acts as if something is missing and the stack trace points elsewhere (down in the document).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple problems:

- missing `\makeatletter` - `\makeatother` pairs
- wrong usage of the key management (family and key name in definition do not match their use)

The following code is a working example. Change the uppercase to a lowercase letter and you'll see a TeX page.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{luacode}

\makeatletter
\define@cmdkey{ECVSS}{X}[Z]{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \makeatletter
  \setkeys*{ECVSS}{X="P"} 
  \directlua{
  if \cmdKV@ECVSS@X == "p" then
    var=1
    tex.print("1")
  end
  }
  \makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. The inconsistencies of the key management were a product of hasty copy-paste. I adapted the example to be more accurate. I'll try the `makeat*`commands and see how does it go.

Comment: @guest_user Did it solve your issue?

Comment: Thank you for following up, @TeXnician. Unfortunately, it didn't. Let me try to adjust the example a bit more.

Comment: I just wanted to share that I succeeded on solving the problem. Although the answer didn't address my problem directly (the whole template is a monster!), it is correct and answers the question. Thank you, @TeXnician